# Array type guard trick

Tags: arrays, typescript

Currently to guard an array type I use 2 functions

A greedy one:

```
export function isPureArrayOf<T>(array: any[], func: Function): array is T[] {
  for (const item of array) {
    if (!(item instanceof func)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

And an unsafe one:

```
export function isArrayOf<T>(array: any[], func: Function): array is T[] {
  if (array.length === 0 || array[0] instanceof func) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

I have 2 questions about that:

Does it exist a better way to guard an array type ?

Can I link func to generic T in someway ? Because currently nothing prevents me to write something like `isPureArrayOf<String>(array, Number)` which is totally wrong.

Comment: Unless you can enforce earlier, you have to trade off speed vs correctness.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm using 2 functions, the first one when I don't control the upper stream, the second one when I just need to make typescript happy (like refining an union).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions a good way to create  a type guard for arrays, I know of no better way to accomplish this. The only improvement is indeed the possibility of tying `func` to `T` for which you need a constructor signature:

```
function isPureArrayOf<T>(array: any[], func: new ()=>T): array is T[] {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. That actually remove the need to explicit the generic when calling the guard (`isPureArrayOf(array, Class)` instead of `isPureArrayOf<Class>(array, Class)`) which is less error prone .

Comment: @Bastien yup, `T` will get inferred from constructor return type, no need to specify it anymore

Answer (score 0):

For the record.

I've updated my trick to accept primitive type (except for `Symbol`):

```
function createTestType(func: Function) {
  if (func === Number || func === String || func === Boolean) {
    // Primitive type
    const expected = func.name.toLowerCase();

    return item => typeof item === expected;
  }

  return item => item instanceof func;
}

export function isPureArrayOf<T>(
  array: any[],
  func: new () => T
): array is T[] {
  const testType = createTestType(func);
  for (const item of array) {
    if (!testType(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```